# Writing values to specific columns with csv.writer

Tags: python, csv

This is my python code:

```
import csv
with open('C://FolderName//File.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for id in (1,10):
        for X in (0,10):
            writer.writerow(id,X,0,"Amazon"); // <- How do i write this using writer ?
```

Desired output in csv file,Example : for id = 1 and X = 0 - 10

```
 1 0 0 Amazon 
 1 1 0 Amazon
 1 2 0 Amazon
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly as pointed out there are mistakes in range function that is you have to use the function `range(1,10)` instead of `(1,10)` as you are assigning a tuple.

and to write you need to have a list

Consider this also

```
writer.writerow(["{} {} {} {}".format(id,X,0,"Amazon")]);
```

For output as

```
1 0 0 Amazon 
1 1 0 Amazon
1 2 0 Amazon
```

If you do

```
writer.writerow([id,X,0,"Amazon"])
```

Output

```
1,0,0,Amazon 
1,1,0,Amazon
1,2,0,Amazon
```

**Post Comment Edit**

Whenever you need to write into a file, the program will request the OS to hand over the write permissions. But however if the file is already opened somewhere else (like excel) then the file will be locked by the OS. This will cause the program to wait till the lock is opened (if it is a blocking write) else will throw `Permission Denied` error. (This will happen only if you use proprietary software.) If you open with Notepad++ this error will not occur

Comment: thank you Bhargav i think it will work but meanwhile i am getting Permission denied: when i try writing to csv file

Comment: @elyon have you opened the output file anywhere else?

Comment: I guess ...it was trying to write to a file for which it could not get an instance of open ..as it was already open ?

Comment: thanks bhargav the above code works great...but where do i make change in the code if i want a pipe delimited output for example :   1|0|0|Amazon. instead of the commas

Comment: @elyon `writer.writerow(["{}|{}|{}|{}".format(id,X,0,"Amazon")]);`

Comment: im getting an error:" 'list' object has no attribute 'get' " which occurs on the line "writer.writerow([id,X,0,"Amazon"]"  I dont think it likes my set, but i have tried with defaults values such as " weiter.writerow(["TEST"])

Answer (score 1):

You were close, here is the working code:

```
import csv
with open('C://FolderName//File.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for id in range(1,10):  # note use of range()
         for X in range(0,10):  # note use of range()
             writer.writerow([id,X,0,"Amazon"])  # requires a sequence [...]
```

Fixes:

- in the for-loops, if you want to iterate over 1,2,3,...,9,10, you need `range(1,10)`, not just the tuple (1,10) - which would only iterate with the two values 1 and 10, not what you wanted
- `help(writer.writerow)` tells you it needs a sequence. Hence you enclose its args in `[...]`
- by the way you don't need double-// in your pathname. You only need to double the slash-symbol if you use \\, because it needs to be escaped in a Python string (unless it's a raw-string: r'C:\Folder\File' ). But anyway, Windows accepts forward-slashes, so just use forward-slash instead of backslash.

Comment: thank you for the correction :) ..i am facing problem when i am trying to write data to csv file ...it says permission denied but when i see the properties for that file it does have full control permisssion set

Comment: @elyon: that would be a separate unrelated issue => ask a separate question. (Who removed the upvote? sigh)